# AngularUI - ui-select multiple value not showing properly

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui

I've an angular-ui dropdown multi-select that does not show the values properly. The input binding box forms a plain box without evaluating my `$item` expression. Something like:

[image: No Expression Evaluation]

HTML:

```
<ui-select 
    multiple
    ng-model ="allPlatforms.selected" >
    <ui-select-match  placeholder="Start Typing...">{{$item.allPlatforms}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (allPlatforms | filter: $select.search) track by item">
        {{item.allPlatforms}}
    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select-no-choice>
        Dang! Sorry bro. Couldn't find
    </ui-select-no-choice>
</ui-select>
```

I've two JSON files being generated and called from server.

PFtypes JSON file looks like
`{"allpftypes":["pf1", "pf2"...]}`

Controller JS

```
$scope.name={};
$scope.allPlatforms=[];

$http.get('server.com/'+$scope.num).then(function(response){
        $scope.name = response.data;
        $scope.allPlatforms.selected = [$scope.allPlatforms[0]];
//I will want to do [$scope.allPlatforms[$scope.name.platform_name]] but I've ignored that for now;
});
$http.get('server.com/pftypes').then(function(response){
        $scope.allPlatforms = response.data.allpftypes;
    });
```

If I remove the multiple attribute and make $select changes, it works just fine. I am not sure what horrible mistake am I making. Still new at Angular and learning. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that I already was inside the allplatforms array and was completely missing the point there. It should just be `$item` instead of `$item.allplatforms`.

```
<ui-select 
    multiple
    ng-model ="allPlatforms.selected" >
  <ui-select-match  placeholder="Start Typing...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (allPlatforms | filter: $select.search) track by item">
    {{item}}

     //or
    //<div ng-bind-html="item | highlight: $select.search"></div>

    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select-no-choice>
      Dang! Sorry bro. Couldn't find
    </ui-select-no-choice>
</ui-select>
```

Leaving this as an answer, just in case someone runs into a similar ui-select-multiple problem. Peace!

Any further changes are welcome :)

Comment: since this is the answer to your question, feel free to mark your own post as the answer to make it even more clear.

Comment: I thought I will do that but was not sure. In any case, can you answer the commented part in the controller JS? I am not sure how to execute that since the `selected` array value should be same as `$scope.name.platform_name`. That would be the broader and more apt answer to my question. @JHixson